# CRON JOBs NOT Running on times designated

Tags: linux, bash, cron, schedule

I'm trying to run some specific jobs at specific times during the day to capture particular data on my db during increments, and I currently have TONS of jobs that run perfectly fine, but these don't seem to run on there designated time, and I often times have to run them on my own.

Currently these are the scheduled times.

**I PRESUME 9AM everyday. As I've checked everywhere and it appears correct syntax.**

```
0 9 * * * bash /home/user/Desktop/CRON/OAK3/dw_3704255.sh
```

**I PRESUME 1:30PM everyday. As I've checked everywhere and it appears correct syntax.**

```
30 13 * * * bash /home/user/Desktop/CRON/OAK3/dw_3704278.sh
```

**I PRESUME 6PM everyday. As I've checked everywhere and it appears correct syntax.**

```
0 18 * * * bash /home/user/Desktop/CRON/OAK3/dw_3704286.sh
```

**I PRESUME 10PM everyday. As I've checked everywhere and it appears correct syntax.**

```
0 22 * * * bash /home/user/Desktop/CRON/OAK3/dw_3704294.sh
```

Now, I've tried changed changing the front zeros to 00, but the same result has occured. I recently changed to single zero, but I believe that's how I've originally had it.

I may just need a sanity check from outside perspective, because it appears right, but any insight would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "these don't seem to run"  When those jobs are supposed to run, what messages appear in the log files (`/var/log/messages` or similar)?  Have you tried putting diagnostics into the scripts to monitor if they started and how far they got?

Comment: Sorry to hear you're having cron issues! Could you go through the steps for [Debugging Crontab on the crontab tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) to give us some more diagnostics info?

Comment: Use [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) *inside* your shell scripts.

Answer (score 3):

I'd assume the jobs will start running, but won't complete for some reason, making it look like they didn't start at all. This is often caused by an environment variable that's set in .profile - cron jobs won't execute .profile and won't have access to these variables.

I'd put a statement like

```
exec > /tmp/dw_3704255.log 2>&1
set -x
```

at the start of your `dw_3704255.sh` script; then you can check if the file appears at the time it should, and check its contents for a trace as well.

Also, i'd replace `bash` with `/bin/bash` to protect against weird PATH settings in the cron process, but i wouldn't assume this to be the cause of your current problem.

Comment: I'd just put `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the script and make sure it's executable (`chmod +x`). And there's no particular need to name the script file with a `.sh` suffix.

Comment: I will take the following suggestions and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the cron log

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```